# Facebook SDK Windows phone

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I am create a facebook app in a windows phone application.

I follow this tutorial to configure my app : 
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/config/

And this one to add a connexion button in my main page :!facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/controls/login-ui-control/

So in my main page I have a Grid with stackpanels for the disposition and the button :

```
<!-- login control -->
                <facebookControls:LoginButton 
                    x:Name="FacebookLogin" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"

                    />
```

But when I launch my application and click in the login button, it go to this page with this error :

[image]

So if someone have a solution or a good tutorial :D

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of functionality you are trying to implement using Facebook SDK??

Comment: The autentication. For now I am just trying to connect my application to my facebook account using .Net SDK.

Comment: Why you don't use WebAuthenticationBroker class for Social Authentication.

Comment: I didn't know this class. It can be a alternative, but I will have more functionnality with the Facebook SDK for .Net. Because today I just want to autenticate, but later I will post on wall etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this Link :
[WindowsPhone Store 8.1 : FaceBook Integration Sample (C#-Xaml)](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/12/windowsphone-store-81-facebook.html)

I hope this link might be helpful for you.

Comment: this is a too old tutorial, as I said i am trying to use the login control provide from the facebook client nuget package. For me following this tutorial do not resolve my problem

Comment: I follow this part of the tutorial : 1.2 Linking App with facebook and this resolve my problem.